# PowerShell: "Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

Tags: powershell, file, move

The code below has been wonderful so far for organising my hard-drives.

I do face this error when I transfer large amounts of data:

Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

This happens when I move a file that is duplicate, **is there a way to rename the duplicate file in some sort of sequence**?

That would be much appreciated :))

```
#   Get all files
    Get-ChildItem "C:\zAa" -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  
#   Get the modified date
    $dt = Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime
    $year = $dt.Year
    $month = $dt.Month

#   This adds "0" in front of the 1-9 months
    if($dt.Month -lt 10) {
    $month = "0" + $dt.Month.ToString() 
    } else {
    $month = $dt.Month
    }

#   Remove leading '.' from the extension
    $extension = $_.Extension.Replace(".", "")

#   Where we want to move the file
    $destinationFolder = "C:\zBb\$extension\$year\$month\"

#   Ensure full folder path exists
    if(!(Test-Path $destinationFolder)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destinationFolder
    }

#   Copy/Move the item to it's new home
    Move-Item $_.FullName $destinationFolder
}
```

I haven't been able to do much, I normally go find the duplicates and rename them manually.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, then please accept it so others with a similar question may find it more easily. See the [tour] on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to move a file with a unique name is to use a Hashtable that stores the filenames already present.
Then a simple loop can add a sequence number to its file name until it is no longer found in the Hashtable.
Next simply move the file under that new name.

Your code modified:

```
#   Where we want to move the file
$destinationFolder = 'C:\zBb\{0}\{1:yyyy}\{1:MM}' -f $_.Extension.TrimStart("."), $_.LastWriteTime
#   Ensure full folder path exists
$null = New-Item -Path $destinationFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

# create a Hashtable and store the filenames already present in the destination folder
$existing = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationFolder -File | ForEach-Object { $existing[$_.Name] = $true }

#   Get all source files
Get-ChildItem "C:\zAa" -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

#   Copy/Move the item to it's new home

    # construct the new filename by appending an index number in between brackets
    $newName = $_.Name
    $count   = 1
    while ($existing.ContainsKey($newName)) {
        $newName = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $_.BaseName, $count++, $_.Extension
    }
    # add this new name to the Hashtable so it exists in the next run
    $existing[$newName] = $true

    # use Join-Path to create a FullName for the file
    $newFile = Join-Path -Path $destinationFolder -ChildPath $newName
    Write-Verbose "Moving '$($_.FullName)' as '$newFile'"
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $newFile -Force
}
```